# mhchem doesn't work in equations properly

Tags: align, mhchem, chemistry

From what I understand (page 11 in `mhchem` documentation), this MWE should be ok

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \ce{a <=>[k_1][k_2] b}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But I get an error. If I place `$` signs around the `$k_1$` and `$k_2$`, the code compile properly an results with the expected results

[image]

What is missing?

Edit:

This is the error I get when compiling (using pdflatex) breaks

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8     \end{align*}

? x
```

Comment: `\ce` must, by default, expect the bracketed over and undersets to be text, which precludes the use of the underscore `_`.  However, delimiting the term with `$` signs causes those terms to be interpreted  in math mode.  The error, therefore, has nothing to do with the `align*`.

Comment: Works fine for me. What error do you get? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: Nothing's missing: the correct usage is `\ce{a <=>[$k_1$][$k_2$] b}` regardless if `\ce` is used in math mode or not…

Comment: The example on page 11 has `\ce{...<=>[+e] ...}`. There the arrow caption is no mathematical expression but a chemical one so no math mode is needed. See page 10 for an example with a math expression: `\ce{A ->[$x_i$] B}`

Comment: @clemens: On my system `[k_1]` gives (as expected) a different output then `[$k_1$]` -- the second uses the math italic k -- but I get no error with both.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer without `$...$` the expression is evaluated as chemical compound and `mhchem` uses `_` for subscripts in compounds. `\ce{H_2O}` is a valid input. But since the `k_1` denotes the rate constant of the reaction which is a mathematical expression and no compound using `$k_1$` is correct. (IIRC in earlier versions of `mhchem` the default for an arrow caption *was* math mode but I'm not sure…)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but you're right: either way there should be no error

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that's not true: the default for arrow captions is a chemical expression. The manual says »The arrow arguments use the same syntax as the `\ce` command.«

Comment: I don't get an error with your MWE. Can you check the error is there when you run it and report your package versions (using `\listfiles` at the beginning of your file) as well as the precise wording of the error message, please?

Comment: @Clemens I am able to recreate the error of the MWE.  However, if I remove the `version=4` qualifier, all compiles nicely.   The `version=4` error is `Missing $ inserted`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes with the current version 2015/07/23 v4.02 of `mhchem`? Which error is it?

Comment: @Clemens My log file reports `Package: mhchem 2014/03/27 v3.17`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes so we know why *you* get an error :)

Comment: @Clemens Sure enough, the last line of the log file indicates as much.  That is an annoying feature of LaTeX that demanding a newer package version generates only a warning and not a meaningful error.

Comment: Thus, proper guidance to the OP is to check the last lines of your log file.  Does it say something like  `Package mhchem Warning: You are using version 3.xx of mhchem. You entered
(mhchem)                the parameter version=4. This means, you are using
(mhchem)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: That's why I asked for the log-file.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I edited my question with the error I get.

Comment: I can confirm that version 3.17 (TeX Live 2013) of `mhchem` produces the error, whereas version 4.00 or later (current is 4.02) doesn't. If I use `version=3` and TeX Live 2013, I get no error, but the labels above and below the arrows are typeset in math italic.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes With the `version=4` option and using `mhchem` version 3.17, there is a warning in the log file: `You are using version 3.xx of mhchem. You entered the parameter version=4. This means, you are using some beta features of mhchem that are subject to change without notice.`

Comment: Oh. I'm using ``mhchem 3.15`` which is what available on linux mint. Shouldn't I get a warning that there is a problem with it when I ask for version 4?

Comment: Your log file should contain the warning, if you look with a fine-toothed comb.

Comment: Yeah, I look again today, and found it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been fixed in the latest version.